# Implementing the minimax

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

Can someone please help me with this? I'm trying to program an AI for my Tic-Tac-Toe game, all relevant searches have brought me to the minimax algorithm. From everything I read and watched I have a basic understanding of the theory behind the algorithm. What I'm having trouble with is the actual application of it in my game. I know that this algorithm is essentially supposed to play out each move and return a score based on the state of the board. How do I make it play a different combination every time? How do I make sure I get every combo? After it finds a winning state how do I return the correct move from that? Am I supposed to store each state in an array? Sorry for all the questions I'm just trying to solidify my understanding and make sure I can actually put into practice the things I'm reading. I am providing my javascript code for the game and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction here. Thank You.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var x = 'X';
    var o = 'O';
    var newgame = function() {
        turn = x;
        sqrData = '';
        xMoves = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false];
        oMoves = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false];
        squareFree = [false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true];
        moveCount = 0;
        compPlayer = false;
        playboard = [false,[false,true,true,true],[false,true,true,true],[false,true,true,true]]
        $('div').html('');
        $('#reset').html('Reset Game');

     };
    newgame();

    $('#fir').click(function() {
       turnchange(1,1,1,$(this));
    });
    $('#sec').click(function() {
        turnchange(2,1,2,$(this));
    });
    $('#thir').click(function() {
       turnchange(3,1,3,$(this));
    });
    $('#four').click(function() {
        turnchange(4,2,1,$(this));
    });
    $('#fiv').click(function() {
       turnchange(5,2,2,$(this));
    });
    $('#six').click(function() {
        turnchange(6,2,3,$(this));
    });
    $('#sev').click(function() {
        turnchange(7,3,1,$(this));
    });
    $('#eight').click(function() {
      turnchange(8,3,2,$(this));
    });
    $('#nine').click(function() {
       turnchange(9,3,3,$(this));
    });
    var turnchange = function(playerSquare,playRow,playCol,sqrData) {
        playboard[playRow][playCol] = turn;
        console.log(playboard);
        if (squareFree[playerSquare] == true) {
            $(sqrData).html(turn);
            if (turn == x) {
                xMoves[playerSquare] = true;
                turn = o;
            }
            else if (turn == o) {
                oMoves[playerSquare] = true;
                turn = x;
            }

            squareFree[playerSquare] = false;
            moveCount++;
            checkwin($(this));
        }
    };

    var checkwin = function() {
          if ((xMoves[1] && xMoves[2] && xMoves[3]) || (xMoves[1] && xMoves[4] && xMoves[7]) ||
            (xMoves[1] && xMoves[5] && xMoves[9]) || (xMoves[2] && xMoves[5] && xMoves[8]) ||
            (xMoves[3] && xMoves[6] && xMoves[9]) || (xMoves[4] && xMoves[5] && xMoves[6]) || (xMoves[7] && xMoves[8] && xMoves[9]) ||
            (xMoves[3] && xMoves[5] && xMoves[7])) {
            $('#game').html('Game Over - X Wins');
            deactivateSquares();
        }
        else if ((oMoves[1] && oMoves[2] && oMoves[3]) || (oMoves[1] && oMoves[4] && oMoves[7]) ||
            (oMoves[1] && oMoves[5] && oMoves[9]) || (oMoves[2] && oMoves[5] && oMoves[8]) ||
            (oMoves[3] && oMoves[6] && oMoves[9]) || (oMoves[4] && oMoves[5] && oMoves[6]) || (oMoves[7] && oMoves[8] && oMoves[9]) ||
            (oMoves[3] && oMoves[5] && oMoves[7])) {
            $('#game').html('Game Over - O Wins');
            deactivateSquares();
        }
        else if (moveCount == 9) {
            $('#game').html('Its a Draw');
        }

    };
    var deactivateSquares = function() {
        for (var e in squareFree) {
            squareFree[e]= false;
        }

    };


    $('#reset').click(function(){
        newgame();
        });

});
```

Comment: I once wrote one of those too, although it seems a bit of a riddle now to follow - http://alhambra.x10.bz/tic-tac-toe/ (`mx` in the source is the minimax function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a `score :: Configuration -> N` function. A configuration is the current state of the board.

We can draw the tree of all possible configurations. Leaves contain the score of the board. `MAX` is you, `MIN` is your opponent:

```
Configuration      Player
        A           MAX
    /       \
   B         C      MIN
 /   \     /   \
D,1  E,3  F,2  G,1  MAX
```

`minmax` is a recursive algorithm traversing this tree. It computes the best choice (based on your `score` function) for the given configuration and the player. Note that `MAX`'s goal is to maximize the `score` and `MIN`'s goal is to minimize it.

```
minMax(c, player)
  if c is leaf:
    return score(c)

  if player == MAX:
    bestScore = -inf
    moves = generateAllMoves(c)
    for each move m in moves:
      c = makeMove(c, m)
      currScore = minMax(c, MIN)
      if currScore > bestScore
        bestScore = currScore
      c = undoMove(c, m)
    return bestScore

  if player == MIN:
    bestScore = +inf
    moves = generateAllMoves(c)
    for each move m in moves:
      c = makeMove(c, m)
      bestScore = minMax(c, MAX)
      if currScore < bestScore
        score = currScore
      c = undoMove(c, m)
    return bestScore

getBestMove(c):
  bestScore = -inf
  bestMove = null
  for each move m in c:
    c = makeMove(c, m)
    currScore = minMax(c, MIN)
    if currScore > bestScore
      bestScore = currScore
      bestMove = m
    c = undoMove(c, m)
  return bestMove
```

`minMax(c, MAX)` returns the greatest score that the `MIN` player can force you to achieve, i.e. it guarantees that no matter what strategy you opponent plays you can always achieve at least `minMax(c, MAX)` score.

> 1. How do I make it play a different combination every time?

Your score function can be random. For example: `score(c) = deterministic_score(c) + rand() * 0.0001`.

> 2. How do I make sure I get every combo?

You have to properly implement the move generating algorithm.

> 3. After it finds a winning state how do I return the correct move from that?

If your `score` function returns `+inf` for the winning state and you always choose the move returned by the `getBestMove` then you'll always end up in the winning state (provided your opponend does not have a counter strategy for it and the depth of the search is unlimited).

> 4. Am I supposed to store each state in an array?

You can just generate all the moves and modify the board on the fly.

Comment: thank you for your hasty and well thought out reply. very useful.